# How to reset 'par' (pty='s') value in R

Tags: r, parameters, plot, default-value

I was trying to plot two graphs simultaneously. I did it using`par(mfrow=c(2,1)` and reset the par to default with `par(mfrow=c(1,1)`.

I was trying to make the size of dots in the scatter plot and ended in trouble. I mistakenly used `par(mfrow=c(,1),pty='s')` and my plot got re-sized instead of re-sizing the size of scatter dots.

Sorry since Im new to R; I want to reset the size to default value. ie, the value for *pty='s'* should go to default. How can I do that!! I tried with `par(opar)` and `par(resetPar())` which I found from stackoverflow, but both returning *could not find* error.

Also, may I know how to increase the size of scatter dot(s)? Should I ask this as separate question?

Thank you for your help..

Comment: you can try closing the plot window ad opening a new one... (of course, that means you'll have to redraw your graphics). To change the size of points, you can use parameter `cex` in your `plot` call

Comment: It beats the issue, but I need to restart the system which will affect my continuity.. Prefer some solution . . Glad that `cex` changes the size of points :) Thank you . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before modifying the graphical parameters with `par` it may be useful to store the previous parameters:

```
old_par = par()
```

Then you'll be able to come back to previous settings by typing `par(old_par)`. For your current problem, default value for `pty` is `"m"`.

In any case, if you don't want to close your current graphical device to get the `old_par` parameter, you can still open a new one `x11()` then the `par` function will concern the new window, and then close it `dev.off()`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Changing the `pty` to `"m"` solved my issue ;-)